# Required attribute is not working in form React

Tags: html, reactjs

My required attribute is not working when I am clicking on submit button in login component.
Here is my login form code -

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="email"
                      placeholder="Please enter your email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      required="required"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="Please enter password"
                      value={this.state.password}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      required=""
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                  {loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : "LOGIN"}
                </button>

              </form>
```

I also checked with removing novalidate attribute in form but still It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `noValidate` from the form attribute in the first line and you are good to go
it worked for me with your code